# When I change the bundle version, GameKit turn-based matches disappear?

Tags: ios, gamekit

My GKTurnBasedMatches disappeared when updating my app, after some tweaking I found that this happens every time my bundle version changes. My app is not yet in the Store, so this is on the sandbox server.

Everything still works; just the matches from the old version will be gone.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-check the checkbox next to "All versions" in my iTunes Connect version, although iTunes Connect already said previous versions were compatible, checking it and saving fixed the problem.

[image: Re-enable All versions in Itunes Connect]